# VSTS build history for a Build definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a VSTS build definitions in our project, Can i get the build results (passed/failed) that ran using that definition (builds started running using the definition since last 6 months) ?

Currently i am only getting last 20 build information ran from that build definition.

Comment: What the retention settings for that build definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it through Build REST API with PowerShell: Get a list of builds.

For example:

```
param(
[string]$sinceDate,
[string]$token,
[string]$defId
)
$uri="https://[acccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/[project]/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$defId&deletedFilter=1&minFinishTime=$sinceDate"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
$result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$statusResult=$result.value | select-object -Property id,buildNumber,result
```

Arguments:

```
-sinceDate "12/1/2017" -token "[personal access token]" -defId "94"
```

Comment: I am only getting last 23 builds(that is what is present in the History section in the build defination)... eventhough i have mentioned the since date from October. i can confirm there are more builds got triggered from this.

Comment: What's the actual REST API URL? Provide the screenshot of history and deleted builds.